# Change feign client returned instance by using property file ( over-ride starter and eureka auto ribbon behavior)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-feign, netflix-ribbon

### Introduction

So we have a starter that we are using as a parent, and this has various Templates and autoconfigurations that load feign clients as well.

The feign clients are using eureka discovery underneath in order to iterate through the services.

So here is an example of one of our feign clients:

import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;

```
@FeignClient(name="decide-proxy")
public interface DecideControllerApiClient extends DecideControllerApi {
}
```

In the projects that are using this spring boot ( and also cloud starter ) as a parent ( in our pom.xml), I would like to be able to go to the properties file and do stuff like this:

```
eureka.client.filter.enabled=true
eureka.client.filter.services.doc-tools.host=localhost
eureka.client.filter.services.doc-tools.port=8015
```

I have a way to do this now, but it involves using Aspects, and reflection, and it seems to slow down my projects - it's a big ugly hack.

So is there a way to possibly do it through a ribbon property or something else?

Without modifying the starter code preferably ?

Question is:
How can we change feign client returned instance by using property file.
Essentially how can we over-ride starter and eureka auto ribbon behavior.

### Current Hack

So I saw the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42413801/1688441

And based on that I created the following which seems to work:

```
   import com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo;
    import eureka.InstanceBuildVersionProperties.InstanceHostFilter;
    import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
    import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
    import org.springframework.cloud.client.ServiceInstance;
    import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClient.EurekaServiceInstance;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import java.lang.reflect.Field;
    import java.net.URI;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Aspect
    public class EurekaInstanceHostFilter {
        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

        private final String versionMetadataKey;
        private final InstanceBuildVersionProperties filters;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Around("execution(public * org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClient.getInstances(..))")
        public Object filterInstances(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
            if (filters == null || !filters.isEnabled()) logger.error("Should not be filtering...");
            List<ServiceInstance> instances = (List<ServiceInstance>) jp.proceed();

            String serviceId = (String) jp.getArgs()[0];
            InstanceHostFilter filter = filters.getServices().get(serviceId);

            if(filter != null){
                instances.forEach( instance -> {


                    try {

                        Class<?> clazz = EurekaServiceInstance.class;
                        Class<?> clazzInfo = InstanceInfo.class;

                        Field instanceField = clazz.getDeclaredField("instance");
                        instanceField.setAccessible(true);
                        InstanceInfo instanceInfo = (InstanceInfo) instanceField.get(instance);

                        String originalHostName =instanceInfo.getHostName();
                        int originalPort =instanceInfo.getPort();

                        //SET THE VALUES

                        String changeInstanceId = filter.getHost() + ":" + instance.getServiceId() + ":" +filter.getPort();
                        setField(instanceInfo, clazzInfo, "instanceId", changeInstanceId );

                        //HomePageURL
                        String newHomePageUrl = instanceInfo.getHomePageUrl().replace(originalHostName, filter.getHost())   .replace(originalPort+"", filter.getPort()+"");
                        setField(instanceInfo, clazzInfo, "homePageUrl", newHomePageUrl );

                        //StatusPageUrl
                        String statusPageUrl = instanceInfo.getStatusPageUrl().replace(originalHostName, filter.getHost())  .replace(originalPort+"", filter.getPort()+"");
                        setField(instanceInfo, clazzInfo, "statusPageUrl", statusPageUrl );

                        //healthCheckURL
                        String healthCheckUrl = instanceInfo.getHealthCheckUrl().replace(originalHostName, filter.getHost())    .replace(originalPort+"", filter.getPort()+"");
                        setField(instanceInfo, clazzInfo, "healthCheckUrl", healthCheckUrl );

                        //hostName
                        String hostName = instanceInfo.getHostName().replace(originalHostName, filter.getHost());
                        setField(instanceInfo, clazzInfo, "hostName", hostName );

                        setIntField(instanceInfo, clazzInfo, "port", filter.getPort());

                    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                });

            }

            return instances;
        }

        private void setField(Object instanceInfo, Class<?> clazzInfo, String fieldName, String value) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
            Field instanceId = clazzInfo.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            instanceId.setAccessible(true);
            instanceId.set(instanceInfo, value);
        }

        private void setIntField(Object instanceInfo, Class<?> clazzInfo, String fieldName, int value) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
            Field instanceId = clazzInfo.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            instanceId.setAccessible(true);
            instanceId.setInt(instanceInfo, value);
        }

    }

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "eureka.client.filter.enabled", havingValue = "true")
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(InstanceBuildVersionProperties.class)
    public class EurekaInstanceHostFilterAutoConfig {

        @Value("${eureka.instance.metadata.keys.version:instanceBuildVersion}")
        private String versionMetadataKey;

        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "eureka.client.filter.enabled", havingValue = "true")
        public EurekaInstanceHostFilter eurekaInstanceBuildVersionFilter(InstanceBuildVersionProperties filters) {
            return new EurekaInstanceHostFilter(versionMetadataKey, filters);
        }
    }


import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils.contains;

@ConfigurationProperties("eureka.client.filter")
public class InstanceBuildVersionProperties {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    /**
     * Indicates whether or not service instances versions should be filtered
     */
    @Getter @Setter
    private boolean enabled = false;

    /**
     * Map of service instance version filters.
     * The key is the service name and the value configures a filter set for services instances
     */
    @Getter
    private Map<String, InstanceHostFilter> services = new HashMap<>();

    public boolean isKept(String serviceId) {
        logger.debug("Considering service {} instance", serviceId);
        if (services.containsKey(serviceId)) {
            InstanceHostFilter filter = services.get(serviceId);
            //TODO:
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Getter @Setter
    public static class InstanceHostFilter {
        /**
         * host to use
         */
        private String host;
        private int port;
    }
}
```

The above code I have noticed caused my project to slow down quite a bit.
Additionally, it's very hacky due to using reflection and aspects.

### Other Ideas

The only other idea is to maybe start playing with conditional loading of configurations within the starter itself. So, I could try to either load one feign client, or another feign client depending on the properties within the application property file.

Ofcourse this would probably mean that we would have to include the debugging support within each template, feign client, and auto configuration for each microservice.

Ideas?

### Update

We tried using the properties file, and one of the ribbon properties plus feign name but this did not work. Something like:

`decide-proxy.ribbon.listOfServers=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following configuration in bootstrap.yml works for me,

```
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false

my-service:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: 192.168.1.217:9010
```

I configure it in my zuul proxy, so that it can refer to services which is not registered in same eureka. This way it will disable all eureka lookups.

---updated---

Refer to following link, it can specify some service to use use specified server list without disable all eureka lookups.
[How to disable eureka lookup on specific @FeignClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360182/how-to-disable-eureka-lookup-on-specific-feignclient), specify

```
 my-service:
    ribbon:     
      NIWSServerListClassName:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
      listOfServers: server1:18201,server2:18201
```

for your service

Comment: Won't this disable all eureka lookups for all services? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, in this way it will disable all eureka lookups. You can refer this link, https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/325 , it seems it's possible to configure specified service by list of servers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360182/how-to-disable-eureka-lookup-on-specific-feignclient, this configuration would be better, specify  NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList for your service

Comment: Please add the answer based on that link. It is exactly what I was looking for. This worked for me: `decide-proxy.ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList` AND `decide-proxy.ribbon.listOfServers: server1:18201,server2:18201`

Comment: Updated based on the link.